# NumberFormat locale leads to error in PdfBox / Boxable

Tags: pdfbox, boxable

I am experiencing a weird error in PdfBox 2.0.20 (+Boxable 1.5) when using NumberFormat to get the € symbol on one machine. On other machines it works with no issues though.

```
NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
BaseTable table = new BaseTable(...);
Row<PDPage> row = table.createRow(10f);
row.createCell(20, currencyFormatter.format(9.99));
float rowHeight = row.getHeight();
```

This works fine on 3+ machines for more than 2 years now. On a new pc I get an error on the last line when the height gets accessed:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+00A0 ('nbspace') is not
>   available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

The error message is weird to me. I did not use the U+00A0 symbol and I think the issue is related to the € symbol.
When I use Locale.US on the new pc, it uses $ and the error disappears. I want to be able to use the german currency though.

Comment: The `BaseTable` and `Row` classes are not from pdfbox but some other library used on top of it. Please mention that library and its version.

Comment: Other than that I'm surprised that there non breaking space is claimed not to be in WinAnsiEncoding because it is.

Comment: You are right. I am using boxable as well to create a table layout in pdfbox.

Comment: The euro symbol is 0200 (0x80) in WinAnsiEncoding, not 0240 (0xA0).

Comment: Probably there is a nbspace between the amount and the unit?

Comment: @BluE what output do you get from `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(currencyFormatter.format(9.99).getBytes()));`?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I get different results depending on the locale.
Locale.GERMANY: `[57, 44, 57, 57, -62, -96, -30, -126, -84]` 
Locale.GERMAN: `[57, 44, 57, 57, -62, -96, -62, -92]`
Locale.US: `[36, 57, 46, 57, 57]`

Comment: `[-62, -96]` is the non-breaking space; `[-30, -126, -84]` is € (EURO); `[-62, -92]` is ¤ (some generic currency symbol - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography) ). Thus, as conjectured above, there is a nbspace between the amount and the unit. Nonetheless, the actual issue is why the non breaking space is claimed not to be in WinAnsiEncoding.

Comment: Will do, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4891 . In the meantime, please replace it with space as a workaround.

Comment: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.21-SNAPSHOT/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating pdfBox to 2.0.22 fixed the problem.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.22

Comment: @TilmanHausherr:
I thought it did fix it, but I am getting the error again now with pdfbox 2.0.21 (with java 14).

Comment: The the 2.0.22 snapshot https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.22-SNAPSHOT/ make sure to delete old versions from your classpath

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that with maven yet. I might wait for the official release.

Comment: In maven, you put 2.0.22-SNAPSHOT, and you may have to add the apache repository in your pom.xml file.